# Using string variable as a json object name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a dynamic string variable created by UI (`valkey` in below code) and I want to use that variable as a JSON key to get a value from TestObj which is a JSON object. But an attempt with the following code has returned an error.

```
 var valkey=$('#cityfrm').val()+"_TO_"+$('#cityto').val();

 if($('#cityfrm').val()!="NIL" || $('#cityto').val()!="NIL")   
   {

    $.each(TestObj.valkey, function() { 
        var durn=this.duration;
        var prc=this.price;
        var curlegs=this.legs;
        // updating ui
     });
   }
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: While the answer below technically answers this question specifically I'd like to point out that this is really very basic javascript. I strongly suggest that you actually learn javascript before trying to tackle something like this. This question is like someone writing code in C and asking how to get the value form a pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestObj.valkey` will look for the key `valkey` in `TestObj`, which is undefined in your case that is why you are getting the error.

If you want to look for a key from a variable you need to use the syntax `TestObj[valkey]`.

Ex:

```
var valkey=$('#cityfrm').val()+"_TO_"+$('#cityto').val();

if($('#cityfrm').val()!="NIL" || $('#cityto').val()!="NIL") {
    $.each(TestObj[valkey], function() { 
        var durn=this.duration;
        var prc=this.price;
        var curlegs=this.legs;
        // updating ui
    });
}
```